# Prove the relation $J$ is anti-symmetric and transitive

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let Str be the set of all text strings. Define a relation J on Str as follows: $J = \{(s, t) | \text{all the letters in s are also in t }\}$

So for example, J("abc", "braces"), J("aaabbb", "ba"), and J(ε, "abc") are true, but J("abc", "bcd") is fals. Remember that  ε is the empty string.
Then

a. Prove that J is anti-symmetric

b. Prove that J is transitive

my attempt: anti-ssymmetric $\to aRb ,bRa\implies a=b $

lets $(s,t)\in J\implies $  all the letters in s are also in t

$(t,s)\in J\implies $  all the letters in t are also in s

from thatcan we say that $s=t?$

what about transtive ?

Comment: $("ab","ba")\in J $ and $("ba","ab")\in J$ but $"ab"\ne "ba"$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah..what about transitive?

Comment: Like inclusion , your relation is clearly transitive.